# Can anyone tell me the reason for this error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, bufferedreader, java-io

THIS IS MY PROGRAM:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Inputing
{
  public static void main(String ar[]) throws IOException
  {
   InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
   System.out.println("\nEnter a value: ");
   int a;
   a=br.read(ar[0]);
   System.out.print("The entered value is: "+a); 
  }
 }
```

THIS IS MY ERROR:

```
Inputing.java:10: error: no suitable method found for read(String)
a=br.read(ar[0]);
^
```

Comment: There isn't a method read that takes only one string type argument. Check the docs here, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: When you wrote `br.read(ar[0])`, what were you trying to do with `ar[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory. There is no `read(String)` method on the `BufferedReader` class. See the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read-char:A-int-int-).

`BufferedReader` indeed has a `read` method that takes 3 parameters - a character array, an offset and a length value - as arguments. You might want to use that variant instead.